Was Palestinian authority asked to clarify its stance on October 7 attacks, prior to its recognition by Spain, Ireland and others?
Several European countries are about to recognize the Palestinian state on May 21 (or soon after that date). The official representative of the Palestinian people is Palestinian Authority. While Hamas, the dominant group in Gaza engaged in a war with Israel, is in open rebellion against the Palestinian authority, the PA (to my knowledge) has not condemned the October 7 attacks that provoked this war. Have any of the governments planning to recognize the Palestinian state demanded from PA a clarification on this matter prior to recognition? (or are they ready to recognize the Palestinian state, even if it openly condones aggression against its neighbor states - contrary to the spirit of the UN resolutions that serve as the basis for its existence and Oslo accords?)

The question could be asked as "has the PA condemned the attacks as of 21 of May 2024.” The rest makes it look like a rant disguised as a question.

@SJuan76 the question is not about PA, but about the states that are going to recognize it.

@QuittingDueToAntisemitism is it better now? Or do you have a suggestion?

Does this answer your question? Did Palestinian leaders publicly condemn October 7th atrocities as immoral?

@Machavity the question is whether they were asked to rectify their position by Spain, Ireland, etc. Otherwise, these nations find themselves in a contradictory position - condemning terrorism themselves, while supporting those who refuse to condemn it.

The TL;DR of the duplicate is that the PA felt Oct 7 was justified. As the attacks were more popular than the current PA leadership, it's highly unlikely anything has changed. The countries wanting to recognize the PA as a country are trying to put pressure on Israel, not change the PA.

@Machavity I don't think they want to put pressure on Israel - it is more about pleasing certain domestic constituencies.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad "wanting to pressure Israel" and "wanting to please domestic constituencies" are not contradictory items. Specially in democratic countries in which there is widespread support for Palestinian statehood.

@SJuan76 the problem is that neither promote Palestinian statehood, nor pressures Israel, but only pleases the domestic constituencies.


if it openly condones aggression against its neighbor states

FWTW, Abbas has condemned in a certain, sheepish way the Oct 7 attack, calling it an 'adventure'. Presumably, the governments that recognize Palestine as a state (or plan to--about 143 as of May 10's UN vote) are not too bothered by this to demand a condemnation in stronger terms, from the PA.
Apparently the PA has become more critical of Hamas (and Oct 7) in recent times compared to earlier statements. The Times of Israel added this detail in a December piece:

Palestinian Authority President Mahmoud Abbas has been condemning Hamas in “every call and meeting” he’s held with world leaders since the group’s October 7 shock attack on Israel but will not do so publicly while the war in Gaza is ongoing, a top adviser to the PA leader told The Times of Israel on Tuesday.

The Irish gov't put out this summary of a conversation yesterday, the most relevant bit thereof in this context being:

The Taoiseach told President Abbas that Hamas is a brutal terrorist organisation and he utterly condemned the barbaric attack on Israel on October 7th last.
President Abbas said he seconded the Taoiseach’s statement that Israel had the right to exist in peace and security with its neighbours.


But were they asked to clarify their stance? Or do Spain and Ireland prepare to endorse terrorism as is?

Abbas' answer in last quote is predictably evasive - it clearly avoids explicitly condemning October 7. But I suppose we can say that the Irish has gone through the formality of asking PA/PLO to condemn terrorism, and the answer allows wide enough interpretations to check the box.
